# How to identify missing dates in a datetime array and consider them within a function

Tags: matlab

I have 2 variables: `date` (in datetime class) and `practices`. I need to know how many practices a subject did per day. However, some days are missed so I need to be able to spot those and tell Matlab to give as output Day X(missing) = zero practices.

Here is an example of my variables:

```
Date:
06-Feb-2016 12:47:32
07-Feb-2016 12:46:24
08-Feb-2016 12:51:10
10-Feb-2016 11:42:46
11-Feb-2016 00:19:46
12-Feb-2016 13:07:36

Practices:
6
8
10
12
16
18
```

Practices are cumulative so I need to subtract Day2-Day1 to know how many practices the subject did in Day1. For example, on Feb 7 subject did 2 practices (8-6). My main difficulty here is how to spot the missing days? In this case, subject missed the Feb 9. How can I get matlab to give me the number of practices for days performed and practices=0 for the missing days?

Thank you!

Comment: Use diff to find where it's longer than one day

Comment: use datetime to generate a date range and then left join (intersect) it to your set (use dates only, ignore the time): https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/generate-sequence-of-dates-and-time.html

Comment: If I use diff to find where it is longer than 24hours, how can I then write my IF condition to have an output for the practices for Datetime<24h and zero for the missing days?